# How to get information from a remote UDP socket? C# & IPv4

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, udp, udpclient

I have hardware that sends information to the address **192.168.0.255** at approximately 5 second intervals (In the following image, the Wireshark software showing the device with IP address 192.168.0.241 sending the message "**Hallo**" to the address 192.168.0.255 on port 7000):

[image]

On the other hand, I have a desktop app made in C # that tries to read that information as follows:

```c
int PORT = 7000;
udpClient = new UdpClient();
udpClient.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT));


private async Task<string> getData()
{
   try
   {
        var from = new IPEndPoint(0, 0);
        while (true)
        {
           var recvBuffer = udpClient.Receive(ref from);
           string result= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recvBuffer);
           if (result != null && resultado.Length > 0)
           {
               return result;
           }
        }
   }
   ...
}
```

It doesn't work (udpClient.Receive never returns information, it is similar to that there is no socket information yet), but if I open a software tool from my PC that allows me to write information to a UDP scoket, the code works wonderfully (udpClient.Receive captures the sent information.)

[image]

Any suggestions or comments?

Comment: What means _doesn't work_ in detail? Does it throw an exception or does it get stuck on the `Receive` call? Have you tried to debug it? We need a little bit more information here ;-)

Comment: I mean that the breakpoint is never reached as indicated in the second image, because it is similar to not finding information in the mentioned socket.

Comment: Have you tried to verify (e.g. by using WireShark) if any data is sent from your device to the pc?

Comment: @MarkusSafar The first image is Wireshark showing the device sending the message "Hallo" from the hardware to the address 192.168.0.255

Comment: Sorry, had some issues and didn't see the image. Ok and if you are using your desktop application, does it send from the local machine or have you tried another machine as well? It could be you have some firewall issue that blocks udp traffic. As localhost usually isn't blocked, it might work on your local machine though.

Comment: @MarkusSafar

Hi. Thanks for the suggestion. It worked by putting the desktop app on another PC. In other words, it (C# code) managed to capture the message from the hardware. I don't understand why from my PC it manages to don't it. The next step is to test it in an android app (Xamarin), that's where it should work. The desktop app was just a test. Merry Christmas

Comment: Great to hear that it works for you ;-)
As far as I know wireshark manages to capture data before the firewall kicks in, so you might have an issue there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MarkusSafar's suggestion, I put the desktop app on another PC and from there it manages to capture the hardware message. I'm not sure why it doesn't work on my PC, but the next step is to test this same code for an app developed for Android (Xamarin), I hope it works there too.

Answer (score 0):

```
    UdpClient client;
    IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT);

private void Connect()
{
    client = new UdpClient(7000);
    client.Connect(endPoint);
    client.BeginReceive(ReceiveCallback, null);
}

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult _result)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] _data = client.EndReceive(_result, ref endPoint);
            socket.BeginReceive(ReceiveCallback, null);

            if (_data.Length < 4)
            {
                //disconnected
                return;
            }
    //now data is anything received and if you want to view it as a string do:
    string result = Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
    //you can also convert it to other things like ints, float, etc
        }
        catch
        {
            //disconnected
        }
    }
```

Comment: That code is incomplete and correcting, it doesn't capture any data from a UDP socket